# Are stochastic processes defined on product of probability spaces?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The following question has confused me lately. Suppose that you have a sequence of random variables $\{\xi_n(\omega)\}$ defined on some probability space $\left( \Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P} \right)$, taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ and Borel measurable mappings $\varphi_k$. Then you define a another sequence of random variables $Y_k$ by

$$
Y_k = \varphi_k(Y_{k-1},\xi_k).
$$

Is $Y_k$ then defined on the product space $\Omega^k$ or on $\Omega$?
The reason why this confuses me is that "philosophically" I feel like there should for each of the mappings $\xi_k(\omega)$ be different outcomes $\omega_k$ in the underlying randomness so that $Y_k$ depends on a vector $(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_k)$. On the otherhand, $Y_k$ is measurable with respect to the algebra generated by $\xi_1, \dots , \xi_k$ (if I'm not mistaken) so isn't it then defined on $\left( \Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P} \right)$?

Comment: Obviously on $\Omega $... $Y_k(\omega ):=\varphi _k(Y_{k-1}(\omega ),\xi_k(\omega ))$...

Comment: The reason that I'm posting the question is that I don't find it obvious.

Comment: @user202542 . If you can write $Y_k(\omega)$ with $\omega\in\Omega$ on what probability space is $Y_k$ defined on ?